# How can I implement an action for a hyperlink?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Like when double click on the hyperlink on the interface the source code doesn't open and no method created?

So, how can I implement it?! Should I create the method by myself or what?!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use linkButton control and handle its click event at code behind.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="ForgotPasswprd.aspx" runat="server" id="myLink"> Forgot your password? </a>
```

Try.

Answer (score 1):

**asp:HyperLink's** do not have any `Actions` in the properties of the hyperlink.

Select your hyperlink properties and click on the (Events) [image].

You should only able to see `Data` and `Misc` sections and you dont find any `Actions` section for asp hyperlink control. Where as select any buttons and do the same you should see `Actions` section for it.

So you cannot implement it by double clicking on the hyperlinks.

Try using a link button as `@Eric Fan` has suggested.

Hope this clarifies